# Multi cooker - with pressure cooker versus without

Tags: pressure-cooker, crockpot

I crock a lot.  My small pot is getting old and it feels like the controller switch is getting weak.  My large crock has a crack but it does not leak (yet).

With the new programmable can start in the AM and set it to go to warm at 2 PM.  Can sear, do rice, stay on warm for 24 hours, ....  Also a lot more money.

Can get a multi cooker with pressure for *instant* meals.  I don't pressure cook and have don't find myself in need of fast meals. If I had a multi cooker with pressure I might come to find fast as the best thing since sliced bread. Not yet convinced a 7 minute stew will equal a 7 hour stew.

Finally to the question.  Are there any slow cooker regrets to a cooker that will do slow and fast (pressure)?

I know it will be brand dependent. I am considering the Instant Pot (pressure) versus the Kitchen Aid (no pressure).

It is minor, but for me the opaque bulky lid is a regret.  If that is the only regret I will get the pressure multi cooker.

Wow, multi-cooker is not a tag.

Comment: The Instant Pot (and many multi-cookers) have an optional clear lid you can purchase. You don't *have* to use the pressure cooker lid when you're using it to slow cook if you add that in to your purchase.

Comment: Some foods will not cook properly without a steam vet to allow extra water out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched from an old-style crock pot to a multicooker with pressure (Instant Pot, if you're curious), and I have no regrets. The pressure cooker is very convenient for things like stocks and braises, and since the inner pot is steel instead of stone it's more convenient to clean (it can go in the dishwasher). I was worried about the opaque lid, but I find I don't miss it. And there are now many more recipes to try, so there's that benefit as well.

I recommend the pressure cooker.

Comment: In my heart I want to go with the non-pressure but so far every opinion is go with the Instant Pot.

Comment: @Paparazzi You won't regret it.

Comment: If your crock is truly ancient, the newer ones incl Instantpot will not cook as slowly. Legal issues with food poisoning. But oh what I would give for grandma's crock of baked beans!

Comment: @PatSommer I bet grandma used bacon fat.

Comment: ...in everything (Oklahoma/Texas). Consistency of beans cooked slow over 8hrs or more beats boiling any day.

Answer (score 1):

What I love about electric pressure cookers is that you get the set-and-forget convenience. No worrry about burnt food,  and fire.

Comment: Thanks but you get set set-and-forget with the programmable without pressure also.

Comment: If you ever need to cook rice, the electric pressure cooker trumps others due to more even cooking. It is supposedly healthier too.

Comment: May I ask how pressure cooking is more healthy?